# There are two dates. How to create a list of the intervals of months between these dates?

Tags: java, list, date, collections, calendar

Example (as 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm').

- java.util.Date begin  = 21.01.2018 00:00
- java.util.Date end   = 20.03.2018 00:00

I want to create `java.util.List<MonthInterval> list` like:

- 21.01.2018 00:00 — 01.02.2018 00:00 (or 31.01.2018 23:59:59)
- 01.02.2018 00:00 — 01.03.2018 00:00
- 01.03.2018 00:00 — 20.03.2018 00:00

My Class:

```
class MonthInterval {
    Date monthBegin, monthEnd;
}
```

I tried to do it myself. However, in the class `java.util.Calendar` I did not understand how to calculate the number of days in this or another month for this year. But I think I went the wrong way. Any ideas?

Comment: Share your tries ;)

Comment: Make use the `java.time` APIs

Comment: why use an interval you are storing every value twice? can have `List<Date> firstOfTheMonth` can do things like `if (firstOfTheMonth.get(1)<= day &&day<firstOfTheMonth.get(2))`

Comment: What time zone or offset-from-UTC did you intend for those date-time strings? UTC? In other words, is that first one midnight on the 21st in Japan, India, France, or Québec (all different moments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use `java.time` API, there is some interesting stuff, using

```
class MonthInterval {

    static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

    LocalDateTime monthBegin, monthEnd;

    public MonthInterval(LocalDateTime monthBegin, LocalDateTime monthEnd) {
        this.monthBegin = monthBegin;
        this.monthEnd = monthEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return monthBegin.format(formatter) + " > " + monthEnd.format(formatter);
    }
}
```

You can do different ways, like

1. With `do-while loop`

   ```
   static List<MonthInterval> list(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end) {
       List<MonthInterval> list = new ArrayList<>();
       LocalDateTime nextDayMonth;
       do {
           nextDayMonth = begin.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
           list.add(new MonthInterval(begin, nextDayMonth));
           begin = nextDayMonth;
       } while (nextDayMonth.getMonthValue() != end.getMonthValue());
       list.add(new MonthInterval(begin, end));
       return list;
   }
   ```
2. With `for-i` loop

   ```
   static List<MonthInterval> list(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end) {
       List<MonthInterval> list = new ArrayList<>();
       LocalDateTime nextDayMonth;
       for (int i = 0; i < ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(begin, end) + 1; i++) {
           nextDayMonth = begin.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
           list.add(new MonthInterval(begin, nextDayMonth));
           begin = nextDayMonth;
       }
       list.add(new MonthInterval(begin, end));
       return list;
   }
   ```

To use as

```
static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime begin = LocalDateTime.parse("21.01.2018 00:00", formatter);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("20.03.2018 00:00", formatter);
    list(begin, end).forEach(System.out::println);
}

// And get
21.01.2018 00:00 > 01.02.2018 00:00
01.02.2018 00:00 > 01.03.2018 00:00
01.03.2018 00:00 > 20.03.2018 00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Interval.of(
    LocalDateTime.parse(                                    // Represent a date and a time-of-day but lacking a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So *not* a moment.
        "21.01.2018 00:00" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm" )   // Specify formatting pattern to match input strings.
    )                                                       // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
    .atZone(                                                // Apply a time zone to determine a moment.
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )                     // Always use proper time zone in `Continent/Region` format, never 2-4 letter codes such as `IST` or `EST` or `PST`.
    )                                                       // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toInstant() ,                                          // Convert from a `ZonedDateTime` object to a `Instant` to adjust into UTC.
    …                                                       // Do the same as the above (the starting point) but for the stopping point.
)                                                           // Returns a `org.threeten.extra.Interval` object.
.toString()                                                 // Generate text representing both moments of this interval in standard ISO 8601 format, delimited by a `/` SOLIDUS character.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `java.util.Date`. That awful class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

The [other Answer by azro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54226262/642706) is headed in the right direction. But there is no need to invent your own interval class. Look to the existing tried-and-true classes found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project is led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne, who led the JSR 310 *java.time* project and the *Joda-Time* project.

In the *ThreeTen-Extra* library you will find two class to represent a span-of-time attached to the timeline.

- [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) — A pair of moments in UTC, `Instant` objects.
- [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) — A pair of date-only values, `LocalDate` objects.

## Moments

If you meant moments, parse your input strings at `LocalDateTime` objects. This are *not* moments, only potential moments, as they lack a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "21.01.2018 00:00" , f ) ;
```

Give those `LocalDateTime` real meaning by assigning a time zone to determine actual moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Adjust into UTC by extracting `Instant`. An `Instant` represents a moment always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Pass a pair of such `Instant` objects to get an `Interval`.

```
org.threeten.extra.Interval interval = Interval.of( start , stop ) ;
```

You can compare `Interval` objects with handy methods such as `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `overlaps`, `contains`, `encloses`, and so on.

## Dates

If you are focusing only on dates rather than moments, then use `LocalDateRange`. We must still process your inputs as seen above, as the date varies around the globe for any given moment. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is “tomorrow” while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

For the dates, take the `ZonedDateTime` objects seen above and extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract the date as seen at that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of that region (that time zone).
```

Make a `LocalDateRange` with such dates

```
org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange ldr = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
```

Like `Interval`, the `LocalDateRange` class offers handy comparison methods such as `overlaps`, `contains`, etc.

## Half-Open

> 21.01.2018 00:00 — 01.02.2018 00:00 (or 31.01.2018 23:59:59)

No, do not define a span-of-time by its last possible moment. That is awkward and problematic. One problem is an infinitely divisible fractional second.

Instead, use *Half-Open* method: the beginning is *inclusive*, while the ending is *exclusive*.

[Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java.time%20Half-Open&t=osx&ia=web) for much more info.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).